# Problem with subsubsection numbering :

Tags: sectioning, numbering, scrbook

I want the subsubsection starts from `1.1.1` instead its numeration is starting from `1.1.0`, where's the problem, note that I used the `renewcommand` that allows you to custom the book or any class's parts, it worked for the subsection, but it didn't with the subsubsection.

Here's the code :

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[openany,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.8cm,lmargin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newtcolorbox{titlecolorbox}[1]{
    coltext=white,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    notitle,
    width=4.8em,
    height=2.4ex,
    before=\hfill
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge}
  {}
  {2pt}
  {\begin{titlecolorbox}{}
  {\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}
  \end{titlecolorbox}
  \vspace*{-3.08ex}\textcolor{black}{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.8em\relax}{\raggedright\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\hfill\fontsize{70}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{blue}{\thechapter}}
  }
  []
  
  

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\Large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{\textcolor{blue}{\thesection}\quad\raggedright\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries{#1}}}}


  \titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\textcolor{cyan}{\thesubsection}\quad\raggedright\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}
  
  \titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]
  {\normalsize}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\textcolor{cyan}{\thesubsubsection}\quad\raggedright\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}
  
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter  :}
\section{section  :}
bla bla bla bla....
\subsection{subsection :}
bla bla bla bla....
\subsubsection{subsubsection :}
bla bla bla bla....
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any thought on how to solve the following problem ?

Comment: Have you tried `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`?

Comment: @Tom No, I'm gonna try it now !

Comment: @Tom It worked, will you consider to edit the code, and publish it as an answer so I can upvote it ?

Comment: That's fine, We have already solved it through the comment. initial `secnumdepth` was set to 2, however `subsubsection` have `secnumdepth` equal to 3, So it will not be numbered. It was not start from 0. It will be always 0 if you don't set the `secnumdepth` equal to 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
```

to get numbered subsubsections and TOC entries for the subsubsections.

Additional remarks:

1. The redefinitions of `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` etc. are not needed. The redefinition of `\thechapter` is enough.
2. Do not use package `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class!

Suggestion:

```latex
\documentclass[
  open=any,fontsize=12pt,
  numbers=noenddot% <- added
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm,hmargin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% loads packages tikz, xcolor, graphicx, ...
\usepackage{fix-cm}% make font scalable

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\newtcolorbox{titlecolorbox}[1]{
    coltext=white,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    notitle,
    width=4.8em,
    height=2.4ex,
    before=\myhrulefill{.5pt}
}
\newcommand\myhrulefill[2][0pt]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #2 depth #1\hfill\kern0pt}

\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \begin{titlecolorbox}{}\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\end{titlecolorbox}\medskip
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.8em\relax}{\raggedright\MakeUppercase{#3}}\hfill#2
}

\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{{\usekomafont{headingnumber}{\thesection\autodot\quad}}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{{\usekomafont{headingnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot\quad}}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionformat}{{\usekomafont{headingnumber}{\thesubsubsection\autodot\quad}}}

\newkomafont{headingnumber}{\mdseries}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\usekomafont{headingnumber}\fontsize{70}{60}\selectfont\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\huge}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Large\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\large\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\color{cyan}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter :}
\section{section :}
bla bla bla bla ...
\subsection{subsection :}
bla bla bla bla ...
\subsubsection{subsubsection :}
bla bla bla bla ...
\end{document}
```

[image]